# Algoritmo sobre juego de dados (dos jugadores)

Tags: c++, eficiencia

El problema que quiero solucionar no es obtener una solución al problema planteado si no, conseguir que sea mas **eficiente**, en concreto, pasar de O(N²) a O(N) o O(N log(N)) si fuera posible.

Contexto: problema planteado en la universidad sobre un *juego de dados*.

Básicamente el juego consiste en lo siguiente: cada jugador lanza un dado y el que consiga la puntuación mas alta, gana.

La "gracia" del juego es que los dados **no son normales**, tienen entre 1 y 100000 caras numeradas cada una con números entre 1 y 10000, dichos datos introducidos mediante teclado.

La pregunta a resolver es, si me dan la opción de elegir primero el dado, ¿que dado elijo para tener la mayor probabilidad de ganar?

Mi propuesta (y solución, creo que efectiva) no eficiente:

```
int main() {
    int caras;

    int tope_wins = caras * caras * 0.5;
    int wins = 0;

    vi faces1(caras, 1), faces2(caras, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < caras; i++) {
        cin >> faces1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < caras; i++) {
        cin >> faces2[i];
    }

    sort(faces2.begin(), faces2.end());
    sort(faces1.begin(), faces1.end(), greater<int>());

    for (int i = 0; i < caras; i++) {
        if (faces1[i] > faces2[0]) {
            for (int j = 0; j < caras; j++) {
                if (faces1[i] <= faces2[j]) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (faces1[i] > faces2[j]) {
                    wins++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (wins == tope_wins || wins == 0)
        cout << "NO GANA NADIE\n";
    else if (wins > tope_wins)
        cout << "GANA EL PRIMERO\n";
    else if (wins < tope_wins)
        cout << "GANA EL SEGUNDO\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Se puede ver como compruebo solo las veces que ganaría el primer dado introducido por pantalla, ahorrándonos algunas iteraciones por haber ordenado antes los valores de las caras.

Según el profesor, debe de haber una solución a dicho problema mas eficiente que esta.

Ejemplo de ejecución:

D1: 4 4 4 8 11 11

D2: 1 1 9 9 9  9

GANA EL PRIMERO

En resumen: te dan a elegir dos dados no comunes (muchas caras con valores en cada una de ellas sin seguir ninguna sucesión). Como elegir el que mayor probabilidad de ganar tenga tras muchas tiradas (gana el que obtenga el mayor valor al tirar, tras tirar muchas veces), pero nosotros solo queremos saber con cual nos quedamos para empezar a jugar.

Comment: no entiendo el problema.. si ordenas las tiradas, entonces no estarias comparando cada tirada entre si...

Comment: Las tiradas en realidad no importan, mi solución comprueba todas con todas excluyendo algunas por la ordenación (ya que puedes afirmar que dado un numero los demas serán mayores) y cuentas las veces en las que el valor obtenido es mayor.

Comment: ok. yo no entiendo lo que tratas de hacer, capaz alguien mas lo entienda...

Comment: Edito la respuesta para dejarlo algo mas claro. En realidad he posteado aquí la pregunta porque es muy rara.. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente he conseguido hacerlo, sin tener que hacer caras*caras iteraciones para comprobar cada una de las posibles combinaciones de dados, comprobando quien gana en cada tirada:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> vi;

const int CASO_ESPECIAL = 0;

int main() {
    int faces;

    cin >> faces;
    int ptr1 = 0, ptr2 = 0;
    int wins1 = 0, wins2 = 0;
    int ptr1aux = 0, ptr2aux = 0;

    vi faces1(faces, 1), faces2(faces, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < faces; i++) {
        cin >> faces1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < faces; i++) {
        cin >> faces2[i];
    }

    sort(faces1.begin(), faces1.end());
    sort(faces2.begin(), faces2.end());

    while (ptr1 < faces || ptr2 < faces) {
        if (ptr2 == faces || (ptr1 < faces && faces1[ptr1] < faces2[ptr2])) {
            ptr1++;
            wins1 += ptr2;
            ptr1aux = ptr1;
        } else if (ptr1 == faces ||
                (ptr2 < faces && faces1[ptr1] > faces2[ptr2])) {
            ptr2++;
            wins2 += ptr1;
            ptr2aux = ptr2;
        } else {
            int repeated = (ptr1 < faces) ? faces1[ptr1] : faces2[ptr2];
            while (ptr1 < faces && faces1[ptr1] == repeated) {
                ptr1++;
                wins1 += ptr2aux;
            }
            while (ptr2 < faces && faces2[ptr2] == repeated) {
                ptr2++;
                wins2 += ptr1aux;
            }

            ptr1aux = ptr1;
            ptr2aux = ptr2;
        }
    }

    if (wins1 > wins2)
        cout << "WINS 1\n";
    else if (wins1 < wins2)
        cout << "WINS 2\n";
    else
        cout << "NOBODY WINS\n";

    return 0;
}
```